# LINUX - grep & comment out lines from fstab

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I'm updating fstab on over 500 servers. Current fstab has old as well as new NFS share lines. I need to comment old lines. For instance:

```
NFS.old - Temp File
LineA
LineB
LineC

/etc/fstab - Current
Line1
Line2
LineA
LineB
LineC
Line3
Line4
```

Run a for loop with input from NFS.old, find line in /etc/fstab & comment it

```
/etc/fstab - Expected fstab
Line1
Line2
#LineA
#LineB
#LineC
Line3
Line4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} ($0 in a){$0="#" $0} 1' NFS.old fstab
Line1
Line2
#LineA
#LineB
#LineC
Line3
Line4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this single line `bash` script with `sed` command

```
while read line ; do sed -i  "s/^$line$/#&/" /etc/fstab; done < NFS.old
```

**Output:**

```
cat /etc/fstab
Line1
Line2
#LineA
#LineB
#LineC
Line3
Line4
```

**Note:**
Super  user only access the /etc/fstap.

Comment: This will strip leading/trailing white space, strip backslashes, expand RE metacharacters, fail syntactically if the NFS.old file contains forward slashes, etc., etc. Not a safe or robust approach. Use awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{old[$0];next} {print ($0 in old ? "#" : "") $0}' NFS.old /etc/fstab
```